# Server is not asking for keys to authenticate

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to configure an `ssh` server, so that it accepts only keys (so disabling the request of the password).

I have already generated the public and private key using PuTTY (under Windows).
I have two users currently, root and amministratore. 
I don't want root to be able to login using ssh, only amministratore can.

What I've modified and done until now is:

1. `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` – see  https://pastebin.com/hp0EQ5hG
2. ```
   root@autoapi:~# ls -ld ~/.ssh
    
   drwx------ 2 amministratore amministratore 4096 May  5 16:22 /home/amministratore/.ssh
   ```
3. ```
   amministratore@autoapi:~/.ssh$ ls -l
    
   total 4
   -rw-r--r-- 1 amministratore amministratore 398 May  5 16:08 authorized_keys
   ```
4. ```
   root@autoapi:~/.ssh# ls
   authorized_keys
   ```
5. **I HAVE REMOVED CHARS IN THE MIDDLE, OBVIOUSLY.**

   ```
   root@autoapi:~/.ssh# cat authorized_keys
   ssh-rsa AAAA.....KKQ== rsa-key-20190504
   ```

What have I forgotten?

Comment: Please show charges to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in question. And what is going wrong?

Comment: There is something odd about output of `ls -ld ~/.ssh` when in `~root`.

Comment: Please show the error you are getting when attempting to connect to SSH.  Running  SSH with extra verbosity (-v, -vv, -vvv) would also be helpful to see what is going on.

Comment: (1) In paragraph 2, you say you are running as root, looking in root’s home directory (`/root`?), but the output is for ``/home/amministratore``. (2) What is your problem?  Is root ssh login succeeding?  Is `amministratore` not working? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you connect with SSH, the client first checks to see what will be acceptable to the server.  That is it asks the whether a particular key is acceptable *before* it actually trys to login.  This means that if a particular key isn't acceptable the client won't even try to use it.

From your evidence the most likely thing is that your `authorized_keys` file is set to publicly readable and your config specifies the default `# StrictModes yes`.  It also specifies `# PasswordAuthentication yes`.  So the key authentication is being rejected by the server and instead you are being asked for a password.  To fix this change two things.

1 Change the permissions on `authorized_keys`:

```
chmod go-rwx ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

2 Disable password authentication in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Comment: Love you, it works!

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly set the config to not allow root login.

It looks like you need to set the permissions of the `authorized_keys` file of amministratore, to 600.